# Crash when trying to save data to coredata from an response Swift Alamonfire

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, asynchronous, alamofire

Well, the problem im having is really strange.

Im uploading a picture and after uploading all the pictures i would like to save te respons path to my coredata tabel.

Im trying to do this with this code:

```
     Alamofire.upload(urlRequest.0, urlRequest.1)
        .progress { (bytesWritten, totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite) in
            //println("\(totalBytesWritten) / \(totalBytesExpectedToWrite)")
        }
        .responseJSON { (request, response, JSON, error) in
            println("REQUEST \(request)")
            println("RESPONSE \(response)")
            println("JSON \(JSON)")
            println("ERROR \(error)")
            if let dict = JSON as? [String: AnyObject] {
                println(dict)

                cd.saveUserPictures(dict["url"] as String,id: dict["id"] as String)

            }
    }
```

This methode cd.saveUserPictures works(i have tested it and only get this error here.
The error itself is an "llbd" error in the log and with error code:exc_bad_access code=exc_i386_BPT
The réponse from the server is:

```
JSON Optional({
id = 31;
message = "messages.added_photo";
success = 1;
url = "fL0cK1/tvXtHvegqIqmmzGz.png";
```

})
and the println(dict)

[id: 31, message: messages.added_photo, url: tvXtHvegqIqmmzGz.png, success: 1]

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: This is too few information. What is the call stack? Are the fields "url" and "id" deployed (if one is nil there is a segmentation fault)?

Comment: The fields URL and ID are deployed, added the return from the server for you

Comment: What's with the callstack?

Comment: i don't get a stack trace only thread 1: exc_bad_access code=exc_i386_BPT and the green llbl in the log(also tryied with breakpoints still no trace) the place in the tread is : 0x10973f662:  nopw   %cs:(%rax,%rax) that all the info i have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the object with key "id" is a number, not a String.
So `dict["id"] as String` won't work. Replace it with `String(dict["id"] as Int)`

Comment: thank you! didn't see that coming! but it works now!